# What is the difference between osgi.startLevel and osgi.bundles.defaultStartLevel

Tags: java, osgi, equinox

What is the difference between `osgi.startLevel` and `osgi.bundles.defaultStartLevel` present in 
 `config.ini` of equinox OSGI implementation. I Also want to know how these configuration items are related to number of bundles to be deployed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two things going on: the current start-level of the OSGi Framework, and the *required* start-level of each bundle.

When the framework reaches a particular start-level, all of the bundles at that start-level get started. So when the framework enters level 6, all of the bundles that are at level 6 are started (but the bundles at level 7 are not yet started).

`osgi.startLevel` is simply the start level that the OSGi Framework will try to reach after you boot it up.

`osgi.bundles.defaultStartLevel` is the start level that any bundle has by default **if** you don't set it to something else.

So for example if you set `osgi.startLevel` to 3 and `osgi.bundles.defaultStartLevel` to 4, then basically no bundles will be started!